# Цепные и соединительные потоки

Tags: java, многопоточность, файлы, терминология

Насколько я понимаю:

`ObjectOutputStream` - это цепной поток.
`FileOutputStream` - это соединительный поток.

Это так или нет?

Отрывок из учебника:
[image]

Comment: Что такое цепной/соединительный? Где Вы это прочитали? Можете ссылку дать в тексте вопроса?

Comment: Походу это кто-то изобрёл собственную терминологию и вывалил её в большой мир. А ты вляпался... забудь срочно.

Comment: Что за учебник?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, Kethy Sierra "Изучаем java" 2-е издание

Comment: О как! Не помню там такого. Видать надмозговой перевод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Терминология не общепринятая, не зацикливайтесь на ней. В книге имеется ввиду, что есть потоки, который соединены с конкретным ресурсом - например с файлом, и есть потоки, которые предназначены объединятся с другими потоками для расширения их функционала. Первые можно использовать самостоятельно, а вторые только объединяя с другими в своего рода цепочку. Хотя, на мой взгляд, это больше похоже на матрёшку.

Answer (score 1):

Если внимательно посмотреть на сигнатуру конструктора `ObjectOutputStream` можно обнаружить что он принимает другой `OutputStream` в качестве аргумента конструктора, в который по цепочке будут передаваться данные:

```
public ObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

Соответственно в книге, которую вы читаете потоки ввода-вывода поделили по этому признаку.